# NGN Stack Caller Id/Details issue

Tags: java, android, voip

I am developing a VOIP application using Ngn Stack library in android. I am getting the issue in receiving the caller's number as I got my own number displayed instead of the caller's number at both the below statements.

```
sipMessage.getSipHeaderValue("f")

sipMessage.getSipHeaderValue("t")

sip:4256380@122.162.166.144:52978

---->which receiver id,not caller id.
```

The bellow code snipet is Part of `NgnAVSession.java` class

```
public static NgnAVSession takeIncomingSession(NgnSipStack sipStack, CallSession session, twrap_media_type_t mediaType, SipMessage sipMessage){
       **Log.e("99", "Inside NgnAVSession sip message ="+sipMessage.getSipHeaderValue("f"));**

        NgnMediaType media = NgnMediaType.ConvertFromNative(mediaType);
        if(media == NgnMediaType.None){
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid media type");
            return null;
        }
        synchronized (sSessions){
            NgnAVSession avSession = new NgnAVSession(sipStack, session, media, InviteState.INCOMING);
            if (sipMessage != null){
                avSession.setRemotePartyUri(sipMessage.getSipHeaderValue("f"));
            //     avSession.setRemotePartyUri("sip:tushar@67.205.89.133");
            }
            sSessions.put(avSession.getId(), avSession);
            return avSession;
        }
    }
```

Please anyone help me  how I will resolve this issue and get correct caller id/details.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a webservice to get caller name.

Answer (score 2):

NgnContact class returns INgnContactService object to get name of the remote party.but it provides you if calling number is saved with a name in your contact list